# AS3 equivalent of spike filter

Tags: actionscript-3, numerical-methods

I have an AS3 based desktop AIR project running on the desktop receiving values from a proximity sensor.

The problem I'm having is there is occasional 'noise' or incorrect values coming from the sensor which incorrectly trigger the application.

So if I have set a near threshold to say 2 ft I might get the following values coming in

```
5.1
5.2
4.9
5.0
4.7
5.2
1.5
5.1
5.2
4.9
5.0
4.7
5.2
```

You can see the one 'outlier' is the 1.5 value which incorrectly triggers the application.
How would I set up a filter to ignore this value?
Should I simply take the 10 most recent and average them?

Comment: Why not. How often do you get these spikes? Or maybe use median?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to average the numbers. How many numbers you average depends on how many points you get and how smooth you want the result to be. You will have to experiment a bit to find the right numbers.

This is often called a [moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average), which will block higher frequencies, aka spikes.